# Two listeners with At.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, mention

Anyone here with a bit of experience with [At.js](https://github.com/ichord/At.js)?

I have the weirdest bug right now. I've checked and re-checked everything 100 times.

I assign 2 listeners to a form. 1 fetches users with the "**@**" symbol, the other fetches events with the "**event:**" text.

The "tagUsersConfig" options work great, but the "tagEventsConfig" behaves weirdly. It fetches the first 5 events, then as soon as I start typing the first letter, the list dissapears, even if I know for a fact (in the console) that for each character I type, it's sending me back the correct JSON objects from the API (all of which are accurate depending on the typed letter).

If I paste the users' API query in the tagEventsConfig (events) one, the "event:" now works. The weirdest part is (and you're going to have to take my word for it), the events API call and its variables are all perfectly correct and valid.

**Theory** : I'm thinking it all has to do with the matcher callback, but I don't see why, since the users' names and event names have the same expected structures (spaces, and sometimes special characters).

```
var userList;
var eventList;

var tagUsersConfig = {
  at: "@",
  displayTpl: "<li class='replyToAtWho-list-item clearfix'><div class='feed-replyTo-img' style='${imageId}'></div><div class='left'><div class='feed-replyTo-name'>${name}</div><div class='feed-replyTo-realName'>${realName}</div></div></li>",
  insertTpl: '<span class="feed-reply-to-name-link" data-userNameReplyTo="${name}" data-userIdReplyTo="${userId}">${name}</span>&nbsp;',
  callbacks: {
    remoteFilter: function(query, render_users) {

      $.getJSON(DOMAIN + '/Skeddy/rest/gem/v1/user?institutionid='+CAMPUS_ID+'&apitoken='+USER_TOKEN+'&limit=10&fullname=' + encodeURIComponent(query), function(data) {

        userList = $.map(data.listT, function(value, i) {
          var imageId = (parse_OBJ(value.i, "ImageId")) ? DOMAIN + '/Skeddy/rest/gem/v1/image/' + parse_OBJ(value.i, "ImageId") + '?sname=CampusSchema&apitoken=' + USER_TOKEN : '/' + ROOT + '/img/avatar-default.png';
          return {
            'userId': value.id,
            'realName': value.name,
            'name': parse_OBJ(value.i, "firstName") + " " + parse_OBJ(value.i, "lastName"),
            'imageId' : 'background-image : url("' + imageId + '")'
          };
        });

        render_users(userList);

      });
    },
    matcher: function(flag, subtext, should_start_with_space) {
      var match, regexp;
      flag = flag.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
      if (should_start_with_space) {
        flag = '(?:^|\\s)' + flag;
      }
      regexp = new RegExp(flag + '([A-Za-z0-9_\\s\+\-\]*)$|' + flag + '([^\\x00-\\xff]*)$', 'gi');
      match = regexp.exec(subtext.replace(/\s/g, " "));
      if (match) {
        return match[2] || match[1];
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  },
  delay: 20
};

var tagEventsConfig = {
  at: "event:",
  displayTpl: "<li class='itemAtWho-list-item clearfix'><div class='feed-item-img' style='${imageId}'></div><div class='left'><div class='feed-item-name'>${eventName}</div><div class='feed-replyTo-realName'>10-10</div></div></li>",
  insertTpl: '<a href="' + DOMAIN + '/website/event-details/' + CAMPUS_ID + '/${eventId}" class="fp-ext-link" target="_blank">${eventName}</span>&nbsp;',
  callbacks: {
    remoteFilter: function(query, render_events) {

      $.getJSON(DOMAIN + '/Skeddy/rest/gem/v1/event?institutionid='+CAMPUS_ID+'&apitoken='+USER_TOKEN+'&limit=10&state=published_expired&name=' + encodeURIComponent(query), function(data) {

        eventList = $.map(data.listT, function(value, i) {
          var imageId = (value.imageId) ? DOMAIN + '/Skeddy/rest/gem/v1/image/' + value.imageId + '?sname=CampusSchema&apitoken=' + USER_TOKEN : '/' + ROOT + '/img/avatar-default.png';
          return {
            'eventId': value.eventId,
            'eventName': value.name,
            'imageId' : 'background-image : url("' + imageId + '")'
          };
        });

        render_events(eventList);

      });
    },
    matcher: function(flag, subtext, should_start_with_space) {
      var match, regexp;
      flag = flag.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
      if (should_start_with_space) {
        flag = '(?:^|\\s)' + flag;
      }
      regexp = new RegExp(flag + '([A-Za-z0-9_\\s\+\-\]*)$|' + flag + '([^\\x00-\\xff]*)$', 'gi');
      match = regexp.exec(subtext.replace(/\s/g, " "));
      if (match) {
        return match[2] || match[1];
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  },
  delay: 20
};

$POST_FORM_MASTER.find(".feed-form.mention").atwho(tagEventsConfig).atwho(tagUsersConfig);
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Oh. Wow. I figured it out.

Before:

```
    eventList = $.map(data.listT, function(value, i) {
      var imageId = ...
      return {
        'eventId': value.eventId,
        'eventName': value.name, // ********** Here was my mistake **********
        'imageId' : 'background-image : url("' + imageId + '")'
      };
    });
```

After :

```
    eventList = $.map(data.listT, function(value, i) {
      var imageId = ...
      return {
        'eventId': value.eventId,
        'name': value.name, // ********** Here is the fix **********
        'imageId' : 'background-image : url("' + imageId + '")'
      };
    });
```

I didn't realize that the variables (ex: '${name}') in the 'displayTpl'/'insertTpl' had to be the actual objects' keys, and not the key names I was giving them in my eventList array ('eventName').

But again, this doesn't make 100% sense, since I'm naming/labeling my own keys in the tagUsersConfig options and inserting those into the 'displayTpl'/'insertTpl' and it's all working fine... So confusing.